# How to access a function from a derived class from a base object

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a vector array with an object and I have it filled with some of the same objects but also I have it filled with some objects that are derived from the base object. But I cannot get access to the functions on the derived object in the array. Is there away to get access to it?

```
vector<BaseObject*> objects;
if (type == 1)
{
    objects.push_back(new DerivedObject(var1, var2, var3));
}
else
{
    objects.push_back(new BaseObject(var1, var2)); 
}

objects[index]->GetFunctionOnDerivedClass(); // How to do this
```

Comment: Usually, when you have something like `vector<BaseObject*> objects` it's because you expect it to contain objects of various types that inherit from `BaseObject`. If all those derived types are expected to have `GetFunctionOnDerivedClass()` then it should be a `virtual` member of `BaseObject`. Otherwise, you have to decide what happens when you try to call `GetFunctionOnDerivedClass()` on an object that isn't of type `DerivedObject`. If `objects` only ever contains `DerivedObject` objects, then it should have pointers to that type instead.

Comment: `BaseObject*` is called a raw-pointer and should be avoided if not explicitely necessary, because raw-pointers have great potential to produce unwanted or undefined behaviour. You may want to have a look at [smart-pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers)

Comment: Raw pointers should be avoided if ownership is a concern, not as a matter of course. Smart pointers are also not bulletproof solutions; they come with their own caveats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example demonstrates, how to use basic polymorphism:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseObject {
public:
    int var1;
    int var2;

    BaseObject(int var1, int var2) : var1{var1}, var2{var2} {}

    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "BaseObject{var1=" << var1 << ",var2=" << var2 << "}\n";
    }
};

class DerivedObject : public BaseObject {
public:
    int var3;

    DerivedObject(int var1, int var2, int var3) : BaseObject(var1,var2), var3{var3} {}

    void print() const {
        std::cout << "DerivedObject{var1=" << var1 << ",var2=" << var2 << ",var3=" << var3 << "}\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr int var1 = 1;
    constexpr int var2 = 2;
    constexpr int var3 = 3;

    std::vector<BaseObject*> objects;
    objects.push_back(new DerivedObject(var1, var2, var3));
    objects.push_back(new BaseObject(var1, var2)); 
    
    objects[0]->print();
    objects[1]->print();
}
```

which will give as output

```
DerivedObject{var1=1,var2=2,var3=3}
BaseObject{var1=1,var2=2}
```

<kbd>[See Example in CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xPP5ex)</kbd>
<kbd>[See Example using smart-pointer in CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1xjfTG)</kbd>

Answer (score -3):

To access private member data, simply declare the derived class or member function as a friend of the base class. See here for more information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: The problem is not access. `objects[index]` is a pointer to the base type. They want to access the derived portion of the object through that pointer.

Comment: If access were the issue, there are also cleaner ways to do it.